# Is there html or js code to give visual focus to a GoDaddy template SEND button if no access to original code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, inline-styles, wcag2.0

I am creating a GoDaddy web page using a pre-formatted template that does not indicate visual focus on the SEND button of a Contact Us form. To make my form compliant with WCAG accessibility guidelines, active elements must show visual focus; however, it is a template and I do not have access to the code to modify the styles directly.

Although I can't access the template code directly, it does permit me to add a section to a page that allows html javascript and css. I would like to understand if there is code or a script I can include in that section to modify the button style?

Below is the button tag code copied from page source using Inspect:

```
<button tccltracking="click" data-ux="Button" type="submit" data-aid="CONTACT_SUBMIT_BUTTON_REND" data-tccl="ux2.contact.submit_form.click,click" class="x-el x-el-button c2-1 c2-2x c2-2y c2-2u c2-2v c2-2z c2-30 c2-3 c2-31 c2-32 c2-r c2-33 c2-1v c2-b c2-26 c2-d c2-e c2-2b c2-34 c2-2i c2-35 c2-36 c2-4 c2-5 x-d-ux x-d-aid x-d-traffic2 x-d-tccl">Send</button>
```

I am not a programmer and would appreciate as much detail as possible. I can view page source to obtain tag and class names to cite as necessary.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the button code instead of putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Include or find an element in your rendered page with an `id` attribute. Then, run the following javascript:

```
let id = '<the id that you want>'
let element = document.findElementById(id)
console.log(element)
```

if `null` is printed, then your answer is no. Anything else, then your answer is yes.

Comment: The only Id I see besides the form label ids appears toward the top of the page - <div id="609ac029-a385-4814-a9f2-e52b53d279a5-bootstrap-container">. Could you possibly type the exact code I should use that will create a blue border color upon focus on the SEND button?  Is there a method to call out the Button tag if we cannot identify the correct id?  I do not have access to the header section. Do I need <script> tags around the code? Thanks in advance!